# How to track all ip sessions on a linux machine

Tags: linux, networking

I inherited several hundred linux boxes and need to establish which machines are talking to which.

Netflow is installed on the network equipment, but not actively used yet. Disadvantage is of course it is sampling, not measuring with 100% accuracy and the small things (a once a day report or measurement session of 10 bytes) would fall through the cracks.

I remember something about an ip_acct kernel module that was able to do this but can't find anything about it.

Is there some tool to get from each machine

ip_source_address:port ip_dest_address:port no_of_sessions no_of bytes

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. For everybody who has the same question: http://conntrack-tools.netfilter.org/manual.html